# How to grant print permission to my applet without modifying java.policy file

Tags: java, printing, permissions, applet, policyfiles

Hi i want to grant

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "queuePrintJob";
```

Permission to my java applet which runs on client machine progrmatically in java. Because i can't change the java.policy class of client.
my applet goes like

```
<applet name="printBarCode" code="printBarCode.TestPrinting2.class" archive="./printBarCode/printBarCode.jar" width="0" height="0"> </applet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically 2 strategies you can pursue here:

- Digitally sign the applet and get the user to click <kbd>Run</kbd> when prompted.  
  See [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) for details.
- Deploy the applet in a more recent JRE using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & use the `PrintService` of the JNLP API to print.  Here is a [demo. of the `PrintService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#prs).

Comment: how to digitally sign the applet..?